# Software/web-tool that shows existing connections between words

Tags: language, thesaurus

Could anyone suggest a tool (a Web app or for OS X) that has the following function?

Given a word → generate all its related words (synonyms) and show its connections (how these words are related).

Comment: Is open-source truly a requirement, as the tag indicates?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "*related*". This could be anything from stemming, synonyms to translations in other languages.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: open-source is preferable.
LukasGraf: the relation here is synonyms.

Comment: @Nariman: Then what do you mean with "connections" if the related words should be synonyms? Wouldn’t a simple list of synonyms be sufficient? -- And for which language(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**WordWeb**](http://wordweb.info/) will meet your needs and requirements.

It is not open-source, but you indicated this is only preferable, and not a requirement.

WordWeb will show you related words, and how they are related to each other.  This includes synonyms, antonyms, similar words, types of, types, parts of, and parts.

- The OS X version is available on the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordweb-pro-dictionary/id442806060?mt=12) ($4.99).
- [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordweb-dictionary/id309627313) (free), Windows ([Windows Store app](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/wordweb-dictionary/ae277b47-0fc0-41e4-81c8-03c3349f3d04) and [Windows executable program](http://wordweb.info/free/), both free) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordwebsoftware.android.wordweb) (free) versions are also available.